# Android custom Json listview - 1 search and 2 select all

Tags: android, android-listview

Hi i am new to android.

1) I have a listview with names and checkboxes. I want to have a search function on this list where the user can search for a specific name.

2) I want the user to be able to select all the names in the listview with one click. When the user press on the selectAll button all the checkboxes should be checked.

I am a total beginner and totally confused.

Thanks

```
public class NewstipsActivity extends Activity {
CheckboxAdapter listItemAdapter;
ArrayList<String> listData;

Button getValue;
Button getchoice;
Button selectAll;
EditText edt;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    getchoice = (Button) findViewById(R.id.getchoice);
    getValue = (Button)findViewById(R.id.get_value);
    selectAll = (Button)findViewById(R.id.selectAll);

    edt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText01);


    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);        
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> listData = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>();

    JSONObject json = getJSON.getJSONfromURL("http://test.com/myurl.php");


    try {

        JSONArray results = json.getJSONArray("results");


        for(int i = 0; i < results.length(); i++){
            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, Object> map=new HashMap<String, Object>();
            JSONObject e = results.getJSONObject(i);

            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            map.put("n_id",  String.valueOf(i));
            map.put("friend_image", R.drawable.icon);
            map.put("friend_username", " " + e.getString("n_newspaper"));
            map.put("friend_id", " " +  e.getString("n_id"));
            map.put("selected", false);
            listData.add(map);
        }


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    listItemAdapter = new CheckboxAdapter(this, listData);
    list.setAdapter(listItemAdapter);

    //problem1 search
    list.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    edt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
    {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged( CharSequence s, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3)
        {

            Toast.makeText (NewstipsActivity.this, "On Search", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged( CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3)
        {


        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged( Editable arg0)
        {


        }
    });

    getValue.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub          
            HashMap<Integer, Boolean> state =listItemAdapter.state;         
            String options="Newspapers: ";

            for(int j=0; j<listItemAdapter.getCount(); j++){
                System.out.println("state.get("+j+")=="+state.get(j));
                if(state.get(j)!=null){
                    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                    HashMap<String, Object> map=(HashMap<String, Object>) listItemAdapter.getItem(j);
                    String username=map.get("friend_username").toString();  
                    String id=map.get("friend_id").toString();  
                    options+="\n"+id+"."+username;
                }               
            }

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), options, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            Intent intent = new Intent(NewstipsActivity.this, NewstipsPhoto.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    });

    getchoice.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            Intent intent = new Intent(NewstipsActivity.this, NewstipsPhoto.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    selectAll.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


        }
    });

}




public class CheckboxAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> listData;    
    HashMap<Integer, Boolean> state = new HashMap<Integer, Boolean>();      

    public CheckboxAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> listData) {
        this.context = context;
        this.listData = listData;   
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return listData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {

        return listData.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {

        return position;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null);

        ImageView image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.friend_image);
        image.setBackgroundResource((Integer) listData.get(position).get("friend_image"));

        TextView username = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.friend_username);
        username.setText((String) listData.get(position).get("friend_username"));

        TextView id = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.friend_id);
        id.setText((String) listData.get(position).get("friend_id"));

        CheckBox check = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.selected);        
        check.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                    boolean isChecked) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (isChecked) {
                    state.put(position, isChecked);                 
                } else {
                    state.remove(position);             
                }
            }
        });
        check.setChecked((state.get(position) == null ? false : true));
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

}